# "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function" is showing when I am trying to open the map using markicon method

Tags: javascript

Why I am getting this error?When I am trying to open a map It is not showing and I am getting the above error.
Please Help me. When I am not adding the  "jquery.min.js" it is working fine.But when I am adding map is not opening at that time.When the map is showing the "quicksearch" method is not working.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8./jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--Quick Search Method-->
    $(function () {
        $('[id$=txtBdoNames]').each(function (i) {
            alert("Search Running");
            $(this).quicksearch("[id*=grdAgentReport] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                    return $(row).children(":eq(" + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                }
            });
        });
    });


    function Openpopup(popurl) {
        alert("Map Running");
        winpops = window.open(popurl, "", "width=1000, height=800, left=15, top=45, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,directories=no,location=no")
    }
    var map = null; var infowindow;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


    function InitializeMap() {

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    }
    function calcRoute(start, end) {

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function markicons(listString) {
        InitializeMap();
        var markerarray = new Array();
        var locations = [];
        var ltlng = listString.split('~');

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i = 0; i < ltlng.length; i++) {
            var loc = ltlng[i].split(",")
            var lat = parseFloat(loc[0])
            var lng = parseFloat(loc[1])
            var curPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            bounds.extend(curPoint);
            locations.push(curPoint);
        }



        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var iconPath = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
            if (i == 0) {
                iconPath = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
            }
            else if (i == locations.length - 1) {
                iconPath = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
            }

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: iconPath,
                position: locations[i]
            });

            markerarray[i] = marker.getPosition();


            (function (i, marker) {

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {

                    if (!infowindow) {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    }

                    if (i == 0) {
                        infowindow.setContent("Starting Point");
                    }
                    else if (i == locations.length - 1) {
                        infowindow.setContent("Ending Point");
                    }
                    else {
                        infowindow.setContent("Point: " + (i + 1));
                    }


                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                });

            })(i, marker);

        }
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: markerarray,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });

        flightPath.setMap(map);

        var dil = $("#map").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            minHeight: 500,
            minWidth: 1024,
            height: 500,
            width: 1024,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "CLOSE": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    //$("#map").style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        });
        dil.dialog('open');
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(locations[0]);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942193/typeerror-dialog-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is included twice. Removing the older one will be certainly enough to solve your problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>
```